# Extending get_object_or_404 to use select_related

Tags: python, django, methods, extend

What i am trying to do is to define a custom method that uses `django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404` and  `select_related`. I have the method defined as follows:

#### models.py

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    # Sample class fields
```

#### helpers.py

```
import models
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def get_sample_or_404(**kwargs):
    sample = get_object_or_404(models.Sample.objects.select_related(), kwargs)
    return sample
```

Now, whenever i try to use this method, i get `get_sample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xxxx'`. Following is how i am using it:

```
sample = get_sample_or_404(slug='first-sample')
```

Could anybody put me in the right direction ?

Thanks.

Comment: the function name is `get_sample_or_404` not `get_sample` is it a typo or a bug? or you have used an alias:/

Comment: @AamirAdnan, it was a typo, my bad, updated the Q.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The kwargs must be expanded:

```
sample = get_object_or_404(models.Sample.objects.select_related(), **kwargs)
```